# Alternative way of setting the debug mode

Tags: rom, usb-debugging

I'm having a problem with my android phone: whichever phone application (contacts, settings, messaging...) I try to run, I get the dialog "The process stopped unexpectedly" and I have to force it to close.

So I want to install a ROM. Problem: I have the debug mode off and there is no way of accessing the phone settings.

Is there any alternative way to set the debug mode on? A market application for example? If it is of any help I have a LG GT540 with Android 2.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to reboot into recovery mode and wiping the device?

Comment: The rom I have is the official from LG and they have disabled all modes. I want to set the debug mode on in order to be able to enable the fastboot mode.

Comment: I wrote a [widget to toggle USB debugging](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4785/is-there-a-good-usb-debugging-toggle-widget-for-android) , problem is you do need to be rooted to install the widget.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `setprop persist.service.adb.enable 1` in a terminal. This works on the HTC Dream; can't say I've needed to do it on other phones, and I can't say if it needs root or not (the exploit on the Dream runs that command as root, so it's completely possible you need root first.)

See this question here for other ideas: [Broken screen while debug mode was disabled. How can I re-enable adb?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12834/broken-screen-cant-adb)

Comment: One question, in order to do this, doesn't my phone need to be recognised by adb? And to do so don't I have to have debug mode on? If so, my problem remains. If not, could you explain a bit further?
Btw, my phone doesn't have a physical keyboard.

Comment: Having your computer recognize your phone (drivers) and having USB debugging enabled on your phone are two separate issues. I was assuming you needed help with the SECOND one.

Comment: My computer recognises the phone when the debug mode is on. If not it doesn't. Any way, it was still under warranty and so I took it to the store and they solved the problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Good, glad the problem is solved. You should answer your own question & accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery mode is not available on the stock LG GT540.

In order to flash a different ROM, you will need to first flash a ROM that has "fastboot" enabled via software updater utility KDZ, as described in [this guide](http://androidforums.com/optimus-gt540-all-things-root/352239-updated-02-november-android-2-3-7-gingerbread-cyanogenmod-7-1-lg-gt540-new-method.html):

1. Download and install LG's Windows drivers for your phone, and make sure your computer recognizes the phone when you connect it via USB.
2. Download the KDZ updater and fastboot binary from [here](http://www.fileserve.com/file/DvS66ex) and extract them.
3. Latest MSXML package is required for KDZ to work, so download it [directly from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3988) and install it on your PC.
4. Download the ROM with fastboot enabled from [here](http://www.fileserve.com/file/7WFyRSK).  Save the ".kdz" files somewhere on your PC (e.g. on the `C:\` drive.)
5. On your phone enable USB Debugging by going to Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Development and make sure the `USB Debugging` option is checked.
6. Connect the phone to PC via USB cable.  When prompted, do NOT activate the Mass Storage.
7. Launch the KDZ updater, change “Type” a “3GQCT” and “PhoneMode” “DIAG”. Click the "Browse icon next to "KDZ file" option, browse to wherever you saved the V20A_00.kdz, and click Open.
8. Click the `Launch software update` button and (patiently) wait for the process to complete.  This can take up to 15 minutes.  The phone will reboot when the update is completed.
9. Repeat steps 5 through 8, but this time around select the `romfastboot.kdz` file.
10. Turn off your phone, press and hold the Camera and Power buttons together, and release when the screen's backlight turns on.
11. Connect the phone to your PC.

You can now use the fastboot module to install a different recovery image (e.g. ClockworkMod Recovery) and a different ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod 7.)

Comment: don't I need to have debug mode on to do this? If I do, my problem is that I'm unable to do so by going to the Settings application as it crashes every time.